# Manipulating data from an ajax call before putting results in div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm calling a page and my returned results is the data of that page (duh). Here's what it looks like:

```
$.get('/myPage.html',function(data){

$('#results').html(data);

});
```

What I need to do is remove an element from that returned data. After I do that, I need to extract just the contents of the `<body>`. Once that's complete, I want to put the results into a variable. The only way I know of to do this is have a container, #results, and send the data there. Once my data is there, then I could remove/extract. Is there a way for me to do this without first putting it into the #results?

Comment: Basically your data is either array type or json type so you can easily perform the modification on data by index or stringifyJSON, whatever is suitable for you.

Comment: The data coming over is actually an HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

we can use $(data).find('.some-selector').remove()

Comment: I tried $(data).find('ul').remove(); and then after sent the results to #results so i can see the change, but i doesn't remove it.

Comment: Tried with .end(). Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/uvY6EhUyUzr6kdHsL88T?p=preview